# Java spring WebClient asynchronous handling problem

Tags: java, spring, webclient, spring-webclient

I tried to modify some Java data by `WebClient` response. I also want to use non-blocking type. The problem is using mono.subscribe method's data handling. I want to change the `validStatus` by `data.contain("now currently unavailable")` condition.

But using subscribe non-blocking type messed up the sequential logics to return `validStatus` that only returns `2 //unknown`.
When i check debug mode to give enough time to data changed, it changed `validStatus`. Without debug delay for solve this problem, I used Thread to sleep 1 second. If I called server less than `10 times` only, the Thread is much more reasonable compare with `WebClient`'s blocking type code. But Using Thread is still slow compare with what I expected. In JavaScript code, fetch/ajax/axios are much easy to handle the data inside the function on asynchronous way.

How can i handle the `WebClient`'s non-blocking type with controlled sequential logics without Thread that reduce the application performance?

```java
 AtomicReference<Integer> validStatus = new AtomicReference<>(2); 
// 0: invalid, 1: valid, 2: unknown

try{        
    WebClient client = WebClient.builder()
    .clientConnector(
        new ReactorClientHttpConnector(
            HttpClient
            .create()
            .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 5000)
            .responseTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
            .doOnConnected(conn -> 
                conn.addHandlerLast(new ReadTimeoutHandler(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
                .addHandlerLast(new WriteTimeoutHandler(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
            )
        )
    ).build();  
    Mono<String> mono = client
    .get() //.post()
    .uri(url)
    .retrieve()    
    .onStatus(HttpStatus::is4xxClientError, response -> {
        // Handle 4xx client errors
        return Mono.error(new RuntimeException("mh Client error: " + response.statusCode()));
    })
    .onStatus(HttpStatus::is5xxServerError, response -> {
        // Handle 5xx server errors
        return Mono.error(new RuntimeException("mh Server error: " + response.statusCode()));
    })
    .bodyToMono(String.class)
    .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(5))        
    .onErrorResume(ex -> {
        if (ex instanceof TimeoutException) {
            // Handle timeout exception here
            System.out.println("mh error : Request timed out");
            // ex.printStackTrace();
            return Mono.empty();
        } else {
            // Handle other exceptions
            System.out.println("mh error : Request error");
            // ex.printStackTrace();
            return Mono.error(ex);
        }
    });
    //mono.subscribe(System.out::println);      
                
    mono.subscribe(
        data -> {
            // Handle the result here
            if (data.contains("now, currently unavailable")) 
                validStatus.set(0); // invalid
            else 
                validStatus.set(1); // valid                    
        },
        error -> {
            // Handle the error here
            System.out.println("Error: " + error.getMessage());
            validStatus.set(2); // unknown
        },
        () -> System.out.println("Completed") // not used here
    );    

}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("something Exception");
    e.printStackTrace();
    validStatus.set(2); // unknown
    return validStatus.get();
}finally{
    if(validStatus.get() != 2) return validStatus.get();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return validStatus.get();
}
```